# Swapping classic load balancer with application load balancer throws: The load balancer X does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, elastic-load-balancer

I used the [firstRun](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-west-2#/firstRun) to create our ECS cluster. The [Whizzard](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02001) automatically creates a **Classic Load Balancer**.

As we want to run multiple containers on the same machine on different ports behind the same Load Balancer port I have switched the Classic Load Balancer for an **Application Load Balancer** by deleting the old one and creating a new one **with the same name**.

Deploying a new Docker Image to our Cluster fails with:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: The load balancer EC2Contai-EcsElast-1R09N14WBDCZK does not exist.
```

I assume the Load Balancer's [ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) is stored somewhere in the [Service definition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html), but I cannot find where.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** The Application Load Balancer is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the Service and created a new Service using the web interface (inside my cluster). It let me chose the existing Application Load Balancer and re-deployments work now too.

Shame on you [Whizzard](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02001)!!